# What is the use of dual input, unbalanced output differential amplifier in an operational amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Why do we use an unbalanced output Differential amplifier and not a Balanced one?

Comment: Do you have a particular circuit to mind?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen that done. So why do you think it's the case?

Answer (score 1):

In most applications the unbalanced output works okay and is simpler and cheaper than balanced outputs, which are normally required only in rather unusual circumstances. E.g.:

(a) when driving high-frequency twisted-pair transmission lines. (The electromagnetic common- and differential- eigenmodes propagate at different velocities so a differential driver is needed to launch a 'pure' differential mode.)

(b) in high-precision applications, where the unbalanced ground currents and finite conductance of the ground paths can cause error signals.